# How do I set the grid cell size in Storybook 5?

Tags: storybook

I'm using **Storybook v5.2.6** and am trying to change the size of the grid lines shown in my stories.

After adding `@storybook/addon-backgrounds` a toggle grid button appears in my Storybook toolbar. Clicking the button plots a 20px grid:
[image]

**I want to globally change the grid size to be 8px** and I have tried the following:

```
import { configure, addParameters } from '@storybook/react';
import { create } from '@storybook/theming/create';

const storyBookTheme = create({
  gridCellSize: 8,
  grid: { cellSize: 8 }, // alternative approach
  brandTitle: 'Hello, World!',
});

addParameters({
  options: {
    theme: storyBookTheme,
  },
  ...
});

configure(require.context('../stories', true, /\.stories\.js$/), module);
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to use this parameter globally, but it seems to be the correct approach because:

1. In the Storybook 'Kitchen Sink' repo, [the `gridCellSize` parameter is set like this, along with other theme variables](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/e520afa6a3013175d8481b14e276b14253ac09da/examples/cra-kitchen-sink/.storybook/manager.js).
2. In [PR #6252](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/6252#issue-263925180) the author makes a change to "Pick up `gridCellSize` from Theme configuration options"

So **I thought my above attempt would work, however a 20px grid is still plotted.**

In the release notes for Storybook [5.2.0-alpha.43](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/CHANGELOG.md#520-alpha43-july-13-2019) they mention the breaking change:

> "Move grid toolbar feature to background-addon".

However, there are no migration instructions

So, the question is, how do I set the grid cell size?

### Update

I've upgraded to Storybook 5.3.0-beta.19 and can now set the grid size on a story-by-story basis, but I'm still unable to set this globally.

```
Button.story = {
  parameters: {
    grid: { cellSize: 8 },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying various permutations, I've stumbled upon the correct configuration.

This works with Storybook 5.3.0-beta.19. I'm not sure about earlier versions.

Rather than setting the `gridCellSize` parameter in the theme, you need to add `grid: { cellSize: 8 }` to the configuration parameters. In your `config.js` file, do the following:

```
import { configure, addParameters } from '@storybook/react';
import { create } from '@storybook/theming/create';

const storyBookTheme = create({
  brandTitle: 'Hello, World!',
});

addParameters({
  grid: { cellSize: 8 }
  options: {
    theme: storyBookTheme,
  },
  ...
});

configure(require.context('../stories', true, /\.stories\.js$/), module);
```

Comment: gridCellSize is not working in StoryBook latest version 5.3.18 and maybe it's not working after upgrade StoryBook version 5.2 to 5.3.18 and I changed few config settings and using main.js, manager.js and preview.js setting files

Comment: Confirm that this works in SB6 too, albeit in the different object structure. :)